# Multple Post actions in one web api controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web Api controller which as 3 post actions here are the actions:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostNewRecomendation([FromBody] PostNewRecomendationMessage newRecomendation) 
public HttpResponseMessage LikeRecomendation([FromBody] LikePostMessage likeRecomendationMessage) 
public HttpResponseMessage UnlikeRecomendation([FromBody] UnLikePostMessage unlikeRecomendationMessage)
```

I am getting an error that there are several action that are valid for the same rout. After looking around for solutons I have added specific routing for thees actions which did not work:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("PostNewRecomendation", "api/{controller}/PostNewRecomendation/");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("LikeRecomendation", "api/{controller}/LikeRecomendation/");
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("UnlikeRecomendation", "api/{controller}/UnlikeRecomendation/");
```

I also tried adding the ActionName attribute to the actions thinking it will match the routing I wrote but still no go.

Can anyone help me make this work?

Thanks

Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that the third part of the url, e.g. PostNewRecomendation, fits to the name of the action, but the routing system does not automatically matchs this. Therefore you have to tell the routing system which action must be used.

```
 config.Routes.HttpRoute("PostNewRecomendation", "api/{controller}/PostNewRecomendation/", new { action = "PostNewRecomendation" });
```

You can also reduce the three routes to one:

```
 config.Routes.HttpRoute("ApiRoute", "api/{controller}/{action}");
```

What I prefer is to use the [attribute-routing-framework](http://attributerouting.net/), because it is much easier, especially if you have a lot of complex routes.

Comment: +1 for mentioning attribute based routing, it is so much easier seeing the routing information in the controller code